# Selenium how to click on this kind of link

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having trouble with this particular link because is dynamic, it doesn't have an specefic name or id, but i know that all those links are inside a span with has a class. I try to get a list of WebElements to get all the spans with the class "more" to get the bunch of links inside but i get this error:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (96, 21). Other element would receive the click: <div class="priceFinderHeaderLogoWrap"></div>
```

this how the html code looks likes:

```
 <span class="more">
  <a onclick="setPID(27272);ta.fireEvent('hotels_lists_engagement_tracking.fired', {type: 'ReviewCount', element: this});ta.setEvtCookie('Reviews', 'ReviewCount', '1461750', 1, '/Hotel_Review');" target="_blank" href="/Hotel_Review-g150800-d1461750-Reviews-City_Express_Plus_Reforma_El_Angel-Mexico_City_Central_Mexico_and_Gulf_Coast.html#REVIEWS">254 opiniones</a></span>
```

my java code:

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.className("more"));
System.out.println(links.isEmpty());

for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++)  {
    links.get(i).click();
    // do something in the web page...
}
```

Comment: Did you read the error: `Other element would receive the click: <div class="priceFinderHeaderLogoWrap"></div>`? You're better placed than us to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
List<WebElement>  links = driver.findElements(By.XPath("//span[@class='more']/a"));
```

Answer (score 1):

As per provided information, links are dynamic which is inside span with class as more. So in the code you tried

```
   List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.className("more"));
```

asking to load all span webelements but actually you need links right?

So if you need to load all links in particular span with class more then try like below

```
  List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='more']/a"));
```

provided that page contains unique span which you trying to get links.Then go for 'for' loop and click on link.

if you still get same issue, then use Actions to click on element. for example like below

```
    for(int i=0; i<links.size(); i++){

        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(links.get(i)).click().build().perform();
    }
```

if your intention is to click on span as per code you tried then try Actions as above to get out of the exception.

Please make a note that there is chance of getting stealelement exception as you are performing click which may leads to page loads and driver loose its references to collected webelements in for loop.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: How does this deal with the actual error: `Other element would receive the click: <div class="priceFinderHeaderLogoWrap"></div>`?

Comment: by using actions means move to link and then click, driver will click correctly. does not click on other element may be div here. i get out same issue by doing this and also it is accepted answer for others also.

Comment: no, i get a similar error `Element is not clickable at point (490.6000061035156, 41.100006103515625). Other element would receive the click: <span class="picker-inner "></span>`

Comment: then we can use javascript executor to perform click  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfd"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);